# How to plot ols with r.c. splines

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, non-linear-regression

I'd like to plot the predicted line of the regression that contains a restricted cubic spline due to non-linearity in the model and the standard error bands.  I can get the predicted points, but am not sure to to just plot the lines and error bands.  ggplot is preferred, or base graphics is fine also.  Thanks.

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
library(rms)

# Fit a complex model and approximate it with a simple one
x1 <- runif(200)
x2 <- runif(200)
x3 <- runif(200)
x4 <- runif(200)
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(200)
f <- ols(y ~ rcs(x1,4) + x2 + x3 + x4)
pred <- fitted(f) # or predict(f) or f$linear.predictors
f2 <- ols(pred ~ rcs(x1,4) + x2 + x3 + x4, sigma=1)
fastbw(f2, aics=100000)
options(datadist=NULL)
```

And a plot of the predicted values of the model:

```
plot(predict(f2))
```

[image]

Comment: @Pascal I'm trying to find out how to plot the line that includes the r.c.s. and I don't know how.

Comment: @akrun  Stop crying for a loss of 2 points rep.

Comment: @akrun  For this question? Yes.

Comment: @Pascal How could this question be improved?  I've provide a reproducible question and provided what I've tried along with a plot of the data I was able to get.  I'm stuck after looking at various posts on rbloggers and the docs and I don't know where to proceed, so I'm asking for help.

Comment: @akrun  So I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: You asked for a ggplot2 solution. Please show your attempts using ggplot2.

Comment: @Pascal I updated the question to include base graphics.  It honestly doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rms` package has a number of helpful functions for this purpose. It is worth looking at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RmS

In this instance, you can simple set `datadist` (which set up distribution summaries for predictor variables) appropriately and then use `plot(Predict(f)` or `ggplot(Predict(f))`

```
set.seed(5)
# Fit a complex model and approximate it with a simple one
x1 <- runif(200)
x2 <- runif(200)
x3 <- runif(200)
x4 <- runif(200)
y <- x1 + x2 + rnorm(200)
f <- ols(y ~ rcs(x1,4) + x2 + x3 + x4)
ddist <- datadist(x1,x2,x3,x4)
options(datadist='ddist')



plot(Predict(f))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(Predict(f))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  That's a start to what I'm looking for.  And also, thanks for the ggplot code as well.  That will save me a bit of time.